# return date value of Focus+Context via Brushing Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, d3.js

I am doing twitter sentiment analysis, where it will show the overall area graph and i would be able to select the range of dates and pick out all or some of the tweets that is within the range.

I am trying to generate a tweet box by using the date slider from the sub chart at [Focus+Context via Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) .

I have the Focus+Context via Brushing working but i have no idea how to return the date value of the sub chart.

[Date slider using Jquery](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html)  seems to look good but the slider must affect the graph too and the tweetbox.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user "brushes" the sub chart you just want the date range of the selection?

Look at the `brushed` function in the example:

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

`brush.extent` is an array of two values, startDate and endDate of the selection.  Here's a `console.log` of a random `brush.extent`:

```
[Tue Mar 26 2002 20:46:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), Fri Apr 18 2003 09:10:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)]
```